# How can I find which index in an array contains an object whose value for a specific key is x?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I want to find out which index(es) in the following array contains an object whose value for the key "id" is x.

```
var arr1 = [
  {
    "id":42,
    "name":"Object 42"
  },
  {
    "id":99,
    "name":"Object 99"
  }
]
```

So for that array, I would want to do this;

```
findId(arr, 42);
//returns '0'
findId(arr, 99);
//returns '1'
```

How can I write a function that does that?

This is different than the supposed duplicates, because those duplicates talk about filtering a simple array for a certain value. This question is trying to filter an array of objects where a certain key has a value of x. None of the duplicates solve the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: More related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: I tried Array.prototype.filter, but that doesn't allow me to filter based on the value of the `id` property of the objects within the array.

Comment: @JosiahSprague: How so?