# Searching for value in specific location in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[
    {
        id: "12345",
        name: "Bryan"
    },
    {
        id: "55555",
        name: "Justin"
    }
]
```

I want to be able to search this array for any item with the **id** of **55555** and then be able to edit that object inside the array I am searching.

The only way I can think about doing this is:

```
function searchme(arr, where, equals)
{
    $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
        if(value.where == equals) return value;
        else return false;
    });
}

console.log(searchme(arr, "id", "55555"));
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your array of objects is named `things`. Then using the `filter` method we can iterate over the list and examine each element for particular criteria. For example:

```
var thing = things.filter(function (item) {
    return "55555" === item.id
})[0]
// {id: "55555", name: "Justin"}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/kexmpchn/)

*Explanation:*

The `filter` method takes a comparative function. Each item in the array is passed to the function. All items in the array that meets the criteria in the function, in this case `"55555" === item.id`, is returned in an array to the assignment target.

Since `filter` returns an array of matches, I'm pulling the zero indexed `[0]` element at the end, so only the object gets returned to variable `thing`.

---

If you want to maintain the object index, that can be added to the object first using the `map` method, then `filter` down to the desired object.

```
var thing = things.
    map(function (item, idx) {
        item.idx = idx
        return item
    }).
    filter(function (item) {
        return "55555" === item.id
    })[0]
// {id: "55555", name: "Justin", idx: 1}
```

[JSFiddle with index](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/kexmpchn/1/)

Comment: Also, is there a way to find out which key the item id was under? So that I could go back into `things` and edit the found item it if I wanted to?

Answer (score 0):

If Somehow you have the string, you can search it with Regex:

```
(?=(?:{[^{]*id\:\s\"55555\"[^}]*})){[^}]*}
```

Tested on regexr.com:

[image]

Comment: I changed the blank with \s, got same result on test tool

Answer (score 0):

Your `return`'s are set up incorrectly.

WIthin `$.each` a `return` only returns to the callback of `$.each` not the outer function `searchme()`. It is in a scope closure. Therefore you are never returning anything from `searchme`.

Also , `return false` within `$.each` breaks the loop

One other point is you need to use `[]` object notation when object keys are variables

Try:

```
function searchme(arr, where, equals)
{
    var result = false;
    $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
        if(value[where] == equals) { // change to [] notation
           result = value;
           return false; // found a match so break the each loop
        }
    });
    return result; // return from searchme()
}
```

There are shorter ways to get the same results but it is important also to understand why code you tried didn't work which is why I stayed with `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

BloodyKnuckles' answer wins on brevity, and is suitable for most cases.

If you are searching a large array that doesn't change much, and are doing so repeatedly, then a linear search won't be the quickest.  As an alternative, you can construct an index that will let you get to what you want a bit quicker:

```
var ArrayIndex = function(arr, key) {
    var self = this;

    var _index = {};

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var k = key(arr[i]);        

        _index.hasOwnProperty(k) ? _index[k].push(i) : _index[k] = [ i ];                    
    }        

    self.contains = function(key) {
        return _index.hasOwnProperty(key);
    };

    self.firstIndex = function(key) {
        console.log(_index[key]);

        return _index.hasOwnProperty(key) ? _index[key][0] : null;
    }

    self.allIndices = function(key) {
       return _index.hasOwnProperty(key) ? _index[key] : null;
    }    

    self.firstItem = function(key) {
       return _index.hasOwnProperty(key) ? arr[_index[key]] : null;
    }
}

var idx = new ArrayIndex(a, function(val) {
    return val.id;
});

var result = idx.findFirst(55555);
```

For large arrays (100,000+ items), there can be quite a performance boost.  The downside is that you have to re-create the index every time you update the array.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/rtz4fsag/5/)