# Conditional query on JavaScript object to return specific name with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JavaScript object that I use to store data for one user that can look like this:

```
output = {
  id: "444",
  trial: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  points: [0, 100, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50]
  }
```

What I want is to query/filter this object, for example, to extract all trial numbers `output.trial` where `output.points > 50`.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects) in another post but it is not quite what I am looking for (it returns an empty array).

```
var result = $.grep(output, function(v) {
    return v.points > 50;
});
```

In other words, I want to give a number of conditions and receive the instances of a name of my object where this is true (preferable as array). In this example:

```
result_after_query = [2, 8]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
var output = {
  id: "444",
  trial: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  points: [0, 100, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50]
};

var result = output.trial.filter(function(el, i) {
  return output.points[i] > 50;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code, it will surely help u

```js
var output = {id: "444",trial: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],points: [0, 100, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50]};

var arr = [];

$.each(output.points, function(index, value){
    if(value > 50)
      arr.push(index +1);
});
alert(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```