# Is there a way to select all JSON objects containing a specific value?

Tags: jquery, json

Let's say you have JSON like the following:

```
[{
    "Rarity": "Common",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
  },
{
    "Rarity": "Common",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
  },
{
    "Rarity": "Rare",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
  }]
```

How can you target the objects that have a shared value for one of the Properties, such as `"Rarity": "Common"`.

Can you do (for the sake of this example, let's say this JSON is just named data): `data.rarity.common`? or would it be `data.rarity("Common")`. The reason I ask is I actually can't seem to find this info anywhere in JSON jquery documentation and I would like to populate data in different places based on specific values.

Comment: You have some extra commas in your JSON. You're likely not finding the information you need in jQuery's documentation because this primarily done without the need for libraries or frameworks - objects, arrays, properties, etc, are all fundamentals of plain JS. If you wanted to narrow down your array to only objects that have `"Rarity": "Common"`, you have a few options, primarily `data = data.filter(x => x.Rarity == "Common");` [**An Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/od78u3xo/)

Comment: Boom, thanks so much! I couldn't seem to find this info. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Not a problem. Added [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/od78u3xo/) to demonstrate. Also, just to be clear, the reason you cannot do `data.` is because data is an *array*. It does not have properties, but rather indexes. The `filter` function I've provided simply iterates through each item (as `x`), and evaluates the condition supplied (`x.Rarity == "Common"`). If the result is `false`, the item is removed from the array.

Comment: You're a god send man! Enjoy your day. Super helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects)

Comment: @DanielBeck will I lose the info on this page?

Comment: @dbrree I don't understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go with plain JavaScript. The variable `common_value` is set to Common as a filter for the rarity. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var json = [{
    "Rarity": "Common",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
  },
{
    "Rarity": "Common",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
  },
{
    "Rarity": "Rare",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
  }];

var common_value = "Common";
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
 if(json[i].Rarity === common_value){
   results.push(json[i]);
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Your're welcome. Remember you can change the ".Rarity" to any key you like for controlling the filter :-)