# JavaScript Pop vs slice methods on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a data set that's several hundred elements long. I need to loop through the arrays and objects and determine if the data in them is less than a certain number (in my case, 0). If it is, I need to remove all those data points which are less than zero from the data set.

I've tried .pop and .slice but I'm not implementing them correctly. I was trying to push the bad data into its own array, leaving me with only the good data left.

Here's my JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].high < 0) {
       console.log(data[i].high)
       var badData = [];
       badData.push(data.pop(data[i].high));
       console.log(data[i].high)
   }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: This would be a good case for .filter()

Comment: `.pop()` does not accept any arguments. It simply pops off the last element in the array. It seems like you are looking for `.splice()` instead, so you can remove an element at a specific index, yes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with `.filter()`:

`const result = data.filter(row => row.high > 0);`

Comment: OP wants the "bad" data (aka < 0) in a separate array. This also does not account for `row.high == 0`, which should be valid.

Comment: No, that's not the question that was asked, that was just one approach that was considered

Comment: "I was trying to push the bad data into its own array"

Comment: @AndrewHeekin Updated my comment, .filter() is better suited for this. +1 for you good sir.

Comment: @AndrewHeekin where is the "row" coming from?

Comment: Just a note: `> 0` is not the opposite of `< 0`, you might want `>= 0` here.

Comment: @J.G.Sable `row` is an arbitrary name given to the first argument of the callback function. It is the current element of the array being traversed. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @AndrewHeekin This works perfectly! You're a rockstar.

Answer (score 4):

In case you need the bad results too.

```
const { good, bad } = data.reduce((acc, row) => {
    const identifier = row.high > 0 ? 'good' : 'bad';
    acc[identifier].push(row);
    return acc;
}, { bad: [], good: [] });
```

Comment: Interesting approach :)

Comment: Don't forget the `ugly`