# how to filter object in javascript by specific key

Tags: javascript, json, object, filter

I've got the following object in an array[0]:

```
   [
       {
        "startDay": "05-06",
        "endDay": "05-06",
        "startTime": "xxxx", 
        "eventType": "craft" 
    },
    {
        "startDay": "05-05",
        "endDay": "05-06",
        "startTime": "1400", 
        "eventType": "art" 
    },
    {
        "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08",
        "startTime": "1100", 
        "eventType": "music" 
    },
    {
        "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08",
        "startTime": "1400", 
        "eventType": "fishing" 
    },
    {
        "startDay": "05-07","endDay": "05-08",
        "startTime": "1400", 
        "eventType": "football" 
    }
]
```

how can I filter this by **item.startDay**? e.g. If the filter was "05-06", the filtered would be:

```
[{
        "startDay": "05-06",
        "endDay": "05-06",
        "startTime": "xxxx", 
        "eventType": "craft" 
    }]
```

If the filter was "05-08", the filtered would be:

```
[{
        "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08",
        "startTime": "1100", 
        "eventType": "music" 
    },
    {
        "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08",
        "startTime": "1400", 
        "eventType": "fishing" 
    }]
```

Comment: Use the `filter()` function with a function that compares the `startDay` property to what you're looking for.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to show at least some effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` method and pass a **callback** provided function as parameter.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
let data = [ { "startDay": "05-06", "endDay": "05-06", "startTime": "xxxx", "eventType": "craft" }, { "startDay": "05-05", "endDay": "05-06", "startTime": "1400", "eventType": "art" }, { "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08", "startTime": "1100", "eventType": "music" }, { "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08", "startTime": "1400", "eventType": "fishing" }, { "startDay": "05-07","endDay": "05-08", "startTime": "1400", "eventType": "football" } ]

let startDay = "05-08";
data = data.filter(function(item){
  return item.startDay == startDay;
});
console.log(data);
```

Another approach is using `arrow` functions.

```js
let data = [ { "startDay": "05-06", "endDay": "05-06", "startTime": "xxxx", "eventType": "craft" }, { "startDay": "05-05", "endDay": "05-06", "startTime": "1400", "eventType": "art" }, { "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08", "startTime": "1100", "eventType": "music" }, { "startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08", "startTime": "1400", "eventType": "fishing" }, { "startDay": "05-07","endDay": "05-08", "startTime": "1400", "eventType": "football" } ]

let startDayParam = "05-08";
data = data.filter(({startDay}) => startDay == startDayParam);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` like this:

```js
let data =  [{"startDay": "05-06","endDay": "05-06","startTime": "xxxx","eventType": "craft"},{"startDay": "05-05","endDay": "05-06","startTime": "1400","eventType": "art"},{"startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08","startTime": "1100", "eventType": "music"},{"startDay": "05-08","endDay": "05-08","startTime": "1400","eventType": "fishing"},{"startDay": "05-07","endDay": "05-08","startTime": "1400","eventType": "football"}],
    match = '05-08';

let result = data.filter(({ startDay }) => startDay == match);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const array = [{
    "startDay": "05-06",
    "endDay": "05-06",
    "startTime": "xxxx",
    "eventType": "craft"
  },
  {
    "startDay": "05-05",
    "endDay": "05-06",
    "startTime": "1400",
    "eventType": "art"
  },
  {
    "startDay": "05-08",
    "endDay": "05-08",
    "startTime": "1100",
    "eventType": "music"
  },
  {
    "startDay": "05-08",
    "endDay": "05-08",
    "startTime": "1400",
    "eventType": "fishing"
  },
  {
    "startDay": "05-07",
    "endDay": "05-08",
    "startTime": "1400",
    "eventType": "football"
  }
];
const elementsWith0508 = array.filter(element => element.startDay === '05-08');
console.log(elementsWith0508);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do:

```
const filteredArray = array[0].filter((value) => {
  return value.startDay == "05-06"
})
```

the return inside the filter function returns you every object that matches the condition and build a new array with it.

Hope it helps!