# How filter array with different parameters using pipes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-pipe

My `JSON` file called `employee` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "E01",
        "name": "neetha",
        "age": 20,
        "gender": "female",
    },
    {
        "id": "E02",
        "name": "Kiran",
        "age": 24,
        "gender": "male",
    },
   {
        "id": "E03",
        "name": "Jhon",
        "age": 28,
        "gender": "male",
    }   
]
```

I have an component called `list` where i am filtering this `employees` with their names using custom pipes like this:

**list.component.html**

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"  placeholder="Search">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-selection-list class="list">
        <mat-list-option   *ngFor="let employee of employees | employeeFilter : searchTerm; let i=index">
            <a mat-list-item (click)="onSelect(employee,i)"><span>{{employee.name}}</span></a>
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
</div>
```

**employee-filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';

@Pipe({
    name: 'employeeFilter'
})
export class EmployeeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(employees: Employee[], searchTerm: string): Employee[] {
        if (!employees || !searchTerm) {
            return employees;
        }

        return employees.filter(employee =>
            employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Now the i am filtering using the `name` property, but i want to filter using `age`,`gender` along with `name`. Using the same input field i want to filter. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just like you(?) did with the employee name

Comment: Pass an object instead of `searchTerm   `

Comment: How can i pass object using input field?

Comment: Or don't complicate the things. Gonna respond below

Comment: @cuddlemeister If he will pass an object pipe will no trigger when value changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use or operator `||`

```
return employees.filter(employee =>
            employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
|| employee.age.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
|| employee.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
);
```

Comment: age is and number, cant use toLowerCase() method.

Comment: you can change it to `age.toString()`

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked for  me ,soon i will update the `stackblitz link`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you need to filter the employee in the pipe as follows:

```
return employees.filter((employee) => Object.values(employee).includes(searchTerm));
```

And your code will look like something:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';

@Pipe({
    name: 'employeeFilter'
})
export class EmployeeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(employees: Employee[], searchTerm: string): Employee[] {
        if (!employees || !searchTerm) {
            return employees;
        }

   //Parse a string to integer for the age
    let searchValue;
   if (!Number.isNaN(Number(searchTerm))) {
      searchValue = parseInt(searchTerm);
    } else {
      searchValue = searchTerm;
    }

        return employees.filter((employee) => (Object as any).values(employee).includes(searchValue));
    }
}
```

To see this filter working see this: [javascript filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects/57820038#57820038)

Comment: Can you edit in this link  : **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-6gqsih?file=src/app/list/employee-filter.pipe.ts**

Comment: @Shankar, See the forked and updated link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-akdhyi

Answer (score 1):

```
 transform(employees: any[], searchTerm: string): any[] {

    if (!employees || !searchTerm) {
        return employees;
    }

    // remove the "id"
    const { id, ...objWithoutID } = employee;
    let values = Object.keys(objWithoutID).map(key => employee[key]);          
    // If you want fast and have a very large array of words, call toLowerCase once-  
    return values.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|').toString().indexOf(searchTerm.toString())!==-1
    })
}
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-pipe-kxyzqk)

Comment: Is this efficient than using `||`?

Comment: Of course yes. Dealing with the object/array is huge advantage when we have more data set.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a pipe for a single output is not really cool. 
You can use it like that on the component:

```
get filteredEmployees() {

return employees.filter( anything you want )

}
```

In html just call use `{{ filteredEmployees }}`.

If such filtering is at least a bit complex and common for multiple components, create a service for storing such functions and call it in the getter above