# Check if a key exists in a SerializedArray

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I serialize before sending the Ajax request.

```
//after serialization
var postdata = [{name: "somekey1", value:"somevalue1"},{name: "somekey2", value:"somevalue2"}];
```

I need to check some data before sending it off. How can I get the object where `'name':'somekey1'`?

Comment: find filter etc

Comment: Do you mean `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`?

Comment: [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects

Comment: Thanks @natel that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find() or filter() method.

```js
var postdata = [{name: "somekey1", value:"somevalue1"},{name: "somekey2", value:"somevalue2"}];

let findObject = postdata.find(e => e.name == 'somekey1');
let filterObject = postdata.filter(e => e.name == 'somekey1');

console.log(findObject);
console.log(filterObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use below code;

```
let result = Object.fromEntries(
  // convert to array, map, and then fromEntries gives back the object
  Object.entries(postdata).map(([key, value]) => {
   //Some condition..
  })
);
```