# How can I return items that match a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `map` which returns me html elements:

```
const activeStep = 1;

{filteredData.map((el) => (
  <MarketItem el={el} />
))}
```

But how I can made some condition, which returns me the same elements which is responding to condition.

So , when `activeStep === 1` , I need to return only elements from `filteredData` which have the key and value like this `el.isSelected === true`, in other case if `activeStep !== 1` I need to return all elements from `filteredData` even `el.isSelected !== true`

Comment: See the answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects) (ignore the jQuery-specific ones, look at the ones using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter` method by passing a *lambda* function.

```
const activeStep = 1;

{filteredData.filter((el) => activeStep == 1 ? el.isSelected : true).map((el) => (
   <MarketItem el={el} />
))}
```

Comment: It always returns elements ``el.isSelected === false``, even ``activeStep === 1 || activeStep !== 1``

Comment: @VladMovchan, I tested on my environment and it works.

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry, in my case ``activeStep ``  was ``undefined``.. but now, when ``activeStep`` for example is 2, it returns not all elements, but elements ``el.isSelected === false``

Comment: If this is the expected result, you could accept my answer in order to help other people.

Comment: It's almost the answer.. When ``activeStep !== 1`` , how I can return all elements, which ``el.isSelected === false & el.isSelected === true``

Comment: @VladMovchan, I understood now. I updated my answer.