# How to filter an array of JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have the following object

```
var ob = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 0,
  }
]
```

How can I filter this to say for example return all where hidden = 1

Cheers

Comment: 1) JavaScript Objects are not JSON (JSON is a string format) 2) `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: See [is there any reason to use the var keyword?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+array+filter&rlz=1C1GCEB_enCA934CA934&oq=js+array+filter&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i512j0i512l9.1817j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 0,
  }
];
let res = arr.filter(x => x.hidden === 1);
// or arr.filter(({hidden}) => hidden === 1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ob = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "comment": "some comment",
    "hidden": 2,
  }
]

let result = ob.filter(x => x.hidden === 1);
console.log("result for hidden properties 1",result)
//Or you can use other condision. Just think like conditional operator but this is kind of different thing 
let result2 = ob.filter(x => x.hidden === 2);
console.log("result for hidden properties 2",result2)
//This condition only pass when hidden properties values 2. otherwise It won't filter and won't give your expected output , or result whatever you say.
```