# Check if object exists in another object tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

hello javascript heroes.
i been suffering from this issue long time.
the problem is that i'm searching inside an object using object as a key of search also using **filter** method.
**like this**

```
let data = [
   {
    name:"Jade",
    role:"admin",
    pass:"0000"
  },
  {
    name:"Jon",
    role:"user",
    pass:"0000"
  },
  {
    name:"Adam",
    role:"user",
    pass:"0000"
  },
]

let result = data.filter((item)=>{
  return {role:"user",pass:"0000"} in item
})
```

i also tried

```
let result = data.filter((item)=>{
  return {role:"user",pass:"0000"} in {...item}
})
```

it always return an empty array.

please let me know if there is any way to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant simply compare objects using "in" operator. You can iterate the whole object and match values. Or simply match all values in objects.

**Sample **

```js
let data = [
  {
    name: "Jade",
    role: "admin",
    pass: "0000",
  },
  {
    name: "Jon",
    role: "user",
    pass: "0000",
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    role: "user",
    pass: "0000",
  },
];
//1: Matching whole object
const isEqual = (user, item) => {
  return Object.entries(user).every(([key, value]) => item[key] === value);
};

let result = data.filter((item) => {
  return isEqual({ role: "user", pass: "0000" }, item);
});
console.log(result);
// 2: Matching values
const isEqua2 = (user, item) =>
  user.role === item.role && user.pass === item.pass;

let result2 = data.filter((item) => {
  return isEqua2({ role: "user", pass: "0000" }, item);
});

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Many many many thanks to you man it really works . you saved my a$$

Answer (score 1):

You could read up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes you could for exemple do and if statment of sort

Comment: Thanks @Wasted-O453

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

do it like that :

```
let result = data.filter((item)=>{
 return item.role == "user" && item.pass == "0000";
})
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but i do not want to use object properties directly because in my logic properties change every time so i want to iterate it  because i don't know them

Answer (score 1):

I think you can cover up the case by using true/false, as your title says to check if an object exists in the data.

```
function check(obj, data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (obj.name === data[i].name) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

In which if you try

```
console.log(check({ name: 'Jade', role: 'admin', pass: '0000' }, data));
```

would return `true`.

Comment: Thanx @Samir Abis , This is also a good answer,